# SCOM - TFS synchronization - how to override rule for a group

Tags: scom

I'm trying to achieve *automatic* TFS synchronization with SCOM. It works as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj899887.aspx. I.e., this works:

[image]

I would, however, like to only enable this for a group of certain windows servers. But I'm unable to do this. My approach is to disable the TFS Work Item Creation Rule for the TFS Connector class, but enable it for the group in question - like this:

[image]

That doesn't work, alas - and it even prevents TFS synchronization when manually setting an alart to 'assign to enginnering'-status, which worked fine before.

I've tried various approaches but my efforts have come to naught. How can I enable the TFS Work Item Creation Rule for just the windows servers I've listed explicitly in my 'ITU-morten-testgruppe' group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this issue down - it does not seem to be possible to override the TFS Work Item Creation rule for a group.

My objective - to only have work items created for specific alerts - seem accomplished by triggering a custom powershell script, á la this page: http://blog.coretech.dk/kra/changing-alert-resolution-state-automatically/

I did, however, have to change the script from the above page to this:

```
#Read out the RMS name
$objCompSys = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem
$rootMS = $objCompSys.name+"."+$objCompSys.domain

$ResolutionState = 248
#Initializing the Ops Mgr 2007 Powershell provider
add-pssnapin “Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Client";
set-location “OperationsManagerMonitoring::";
new-managementGroupConnection -ConnectionString:$rootMS;
set-location $rootMS;
$Alerts = get-alert -criteria "ResolutionState = 0 AND Severity = 1 AND Name LIKE 'ITU%'"

foreach($Alert in $Alerts)
{
$Alert.Name

$Alert.ResolutionState = $ResolutionState
$Alert.Update("Resolution State changed automatically by the notificaton")

}
```

Note that the above script can't be tested by using the standard powershell prompt - it must be the tested by way of the 'operations manager shell'.

Hope this might help others in the same situation.